# IPSec VPN on Juniper MX80

Tags: vpn, juniper-mx

Does anyone know how, if at all supported, to setup site-to-site IKE/IPSec VPN end-point on a Juniper MX80 router? The other side is SRX640, so not a problem.

Juniper online documentation is very confusing in this regard. Looks like I either need additional hardware on the router (which?), or I am completely missing something.

The MX80 runs Junos 11.2R3.3.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the Junos documentation for IPSec is pretty confusing; it took a while to find a definitive reference for how to get IPSec in HW on the MX80.

Since you're looking for site-to-site VPN support, this means higher throughput and certainly you don't want to do this on a CPU.  As such, you should use the [MS-MIC-16G](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.2/topics/concept/ms-mic-and-mpc-overview.html), which started supporting IPSec VPN in Junos 13.2.  According to the [Junos 13.2 Release Notes](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.2/information-products/topic-collections/release-notes/13.2/index.html?topic-76116.html), only IPv4 is supported at this time.